# Google Cloud Storage: Count noncurrent objects

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a GCS bucket with files in it. At some points in the bucket history object versioning was turned on. After that we've turned off the object versioning.

Now, we want to validate that all the versions of the files was removed from the bucket. One option to do it, it to create a new lifecycle rule that remove this type of objects.

How we can count how many versioned objects we have on a specific bucket?
If this is impossible, is it possible to know that at least 1 versioned object exists?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this document [List noncurrent object versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-versioned-objects#list), you can run the following command .

Use the `gcloud storage ls --all-versions` command:

```
gcloud storage ls --all-versions gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Where `BUCKET_NAME` is the name of the relevant bucket

This command will list all objects in the bucket, including both live and noncurrent versions

**Note:** Use the --long flag along with the --all-versions flag to get metageneration numbers in the response. Use the --full flag along with the --all-versions flag to get the Noncurrent Time for noncurrent versions of an object.